# Extending parameters for Membership.CreateUser method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I use this code to call my custom membership-provider method :

```
 Membership.CreateUser(newUser.UserName, newUser.Password);
```

but I need to extend some parameters. I have written this to override method :

```
 public override MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, 
    string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, object providerUserKey, out MembershipCreateStatus status)
{
    try
    {
        int max = 1;
        int RoleID = 0;
        using (var context = new KowsarSiteEntities())
        {
            max += (from i in context.aspnet_Users
                    select i).Max(itm => itm.UserId);
            RoleID = (from v in context.aspnet_Roles
                      where v.RoleName.ToLower().Equals(RoleName)
                      select v.RoleId).FirstOrDefault();
            KowsarSiteModel.aspnet_Membership member =                    
                KowsarSiteModel.aspnet_Membership.Createaspnet_Membership
                    (ApplicationID, max, GetHashedPassword(password), 1);
            KowsarSiteModel.aspnet_Users ASPNETusers = 
                KowsarSiteModel.aspnet_Users.Createaspnet_Users(ApplicationID, max, username);
            KowsarSiteModel.aspnet_UsersInRoles userInRoles =
                KowsarSiteModel.aspnet_UsersInRoles.Createaspnet_UsersInRoles(max, RoleID);
            context.AddToaspnet_Membership(member);
            context.AddToaspnet_Users(ASPNETusers);
            context.AddToaspnet_UsersInRoles(userInRoles);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        status = MembershipCreateStatus.Success;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string str = ex.Message;
        status = MembershipCreateStatus.UserRejected;
    }
    return null;
}
```

I need to add some parameters to CreateUser method but How it is possible Membership is a static class how I can customize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
((YourProviderType)Membership.Provider).CreateUser(yourParameters);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the static class provided by System.Web.Security if you're not going to conform to their interface.

As abatishchev has pointed out, however, you don't have to use the static class; you can always use your own class instead.